# Getting event to fire in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The `DropdownListDecks_SelectedIndexChanged` procedure is never called.

```
<asp:DropDownList
        ID="DropDownListDecks"
        runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceDecks"
        DataTextField="DeckName"
        viewStateMode="Enabled" 
        DataValueField="DeckBackImageString" 
        CausesValidation="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListDecks_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: are you sure this is a mvc app? this is not how we create dropdowns in mvc.

Comment: Your tagging is not correct. First of all, your sample is from Web Forms and not MVC. I have removed MVC tag just so that it does not confuse other developers.

Answer (score 5):

Set `autopostback=true` in the ASP DropDownList control.

Answer (score 0):

If u r using mvc framework, then this is not the way to create dropdown.

but in your case just set autopostback property to true.

AutoPostback="true"